# select method equivalent to retain indices only in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

Say I have this array in Ruby:

```
a=[1,2,3]
```

And I want just the indices of the elements that are bigger than 2, not the elements themselves. Is there an Array method that will do the equivalent to:

```
d=[]
a.each_with_index{ |x, i| d.push(i) if x > 2 }
```

Something like:

```
a.select_index{ | x | x > 2 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Array indices are artifacts, and in Ruby programming, you usually should not need to refer to them directly like this. That is the reason there is no single method to do this. I feel there is a code smell in what you are doing.

Comment: It is for quick reference/indexing, based on metadata. I am dealing with huge amount of data, and this is for the "hot parts" w/o needing to JRuby. Makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

You can do :

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.each_index.select { |i| a[i] > 2 }
# => [2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> a = [1, 2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
> a.map { |n| a.index(n) if n > 2 }.compact
=> [2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as short as Arup's and Elle's answers, but the following refers to `a` only once.

```
a.to_enum.with_index.select{|x, _| x > 2}.map(&:last)
# => [2]
```